# Heap corruption from doing SSE memory copy - CRT checks can't find anything

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sse, heap-corruption

I am trying to implement a memory copy function that uses SSE instructions:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef unsigned int uint;

    __forceinline static void SIMD_Copy(void* __restrict destination, void* __restrict source, const uint count)
    {
        //assert(count > 16)

        #ifdef _M_IX86
        const uint register_count = 8;
        const uint step = register_count * 16;
        const uint loop = count / (step);           
        #else
        const uint register_count = 16;
        const uint step = register_count * 16;
        const uint loop = count / (step);
        #endif
        //assert(loop);

        byte* from = static_cast<byte*>(source);
        byte* to = static_cast<byte*>(destination);

        uint debug_test = 0;
        register uint counter = 0;
        do
        {
            debug_test += step;
            from += step;
            to += step;

            _mm_prefetch((const char*)(from), _MM_HINT_T0); 
            _mm_prefetch((const char*)(from + 16), _MM_HINT_T0);
            _mm_prefetch((const char*)(from + 32), _MM_HINT_T0);
            _mm_prefetch((const char*)(from + 48), _MM_HINT_T0);
            _mm_prefetch((const char*)(from + 64), _MM_HINT_T0);
            _mm_prefetch((const char*)(from + 80), _MM_HINT_T0);
            _mm_prefetch((const char*)(from + 96), _MM_HINT_T0);
            _mm_prefetch((const char*)(from + 112), _MM_HINT_T0);
            #ifdef _M_AMD64
            _mm_prefetch((const char*)(from + 128), _MM_HINT_T0);
            _mm_prefetch((const char*)(from + 144), _MM_HINT_T0);
            _mm_prefetch((const char*)(from + 160), _MM_HINT_T0);
            _mm_prefetch((const char*)(from + 176), _MM_HINT_T0);
            _mm_prefetch((const char*)(from + 192), _MM_HINT_T0);
            _mm_prefetch((const char*)(from + 208), _MM_HINT_T0);
            _mm_prefetch((const char*)(from + 224), _MM_HINT_T0);
            _mm_prefetch((const char*)(from + 240), _MM_HINT_T0);
            #endif

            _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(to), _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(from)));
            _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(to + 16), _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(from + 16)));
            _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(to + 32), _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(from + 32)));
            _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(to + 48), _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(from + 48)));
            _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(to + 64), _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(from + 64)));
            _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(to + 80), _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(from + 80)));
            _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(to + 96), _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(from + 96)));
            _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(to + 112), _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(from + 112)));
            #ifdef _M_AMD64
            _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(to + 128), _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(from + 128)));
            _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(to + 144), _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(from + 144)));
            _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(to + 160), _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(from + 160)));
            _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(to + 176), _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(from + 176)));
            _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(to + 192), _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(from + 192)));
            _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(to + 208), _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(from + 208)));
            _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(to + 224), _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(from + 224)));
            _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(to + 240), _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(from + 240)));
            #endif

            counter++;
        }
        while(counter < loop);
    }
```

Here is how I run it:

```
byte* arr1 = (byte*)_aligned_malloc(100 * 256, 16);
byte* arr2 = (byte*)_aligned_malloc(100 * 256, 16);

SIMD_Copy(arr2, arr1, 100 * 256);
_aligned_free(arr1);
_aligned_free(arr2);
```

The arrays are a size multiple of 256, since it copies a minimum of 256 bytes on x64, so I'm keeping it simple. As soon as it reaches the first _aligned_free call, I get:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x77775C0C (ntdll.dll) in MyProgram.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x777A6478).
```

When I hit continue, it goes on to:

```
Exception thrown at 0x776DEE01 (ntdll.dll) in MyProgram.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

Adding:

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF | _CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF | _CRTDBG_CHECK_CRT_DF | _CRTDBG_DELAY_FREE_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_CHECK_EVERY_16_DF);
```

to the beginning of main doesn't seem to be helping. Is there any other way I can find out what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        from += step;
        to += step;
```

happens *before* you use it.  So the last iteration goes `step` bytes past the end of the arrays.

---

#### Other stuff I noticed:

I see a performance problem right away: You only need to prefetch once per cache line (64B), not every 16B.  Intel IvB has a performance bug with prefetch: it can't retire them very fast at all, so you can actually bottleneck on prefetch instructions.  On other CPUs you're just wasting instruction throughput.

---

Also, what's the point of using more `store(load())` pairs on AMD64?  Are you expecting the compiler to order the loads ahead of the stores?  If so, you should store the load results in variables.  I'd expect this code to compile to a sequence of `movdqa xmm0, [src] / movdqa [dest], xmm0`, reusing the same register.  (Which is fine because of register renaming, but doesn't separate loads from stores.)  Also, for large aligned multiple-of-16 copies, `rep movsd` does very well.

One slightly hidden advantage of rep movsd is that it lets the front-end get ahead, and have lots of future instructions queued up for the out-of-order core.  A copy loop keeps the frontend busy with itself.  Also, it doesn't require perfect branch-prediction to avoid a mispredict at the end of the copy loop.

IIRC, SSE copy can be a better choice for smaller, unaligned, or non-multiple-of-16 blocks.  Microcode

Comment: Aren't there twice as much xmm registers on x64?

Comment: @shortage_radeon: there are twice as many, but your code doesn't take advantage of them.  In source code order, you're alternating loads and stores, rather than doing a block of 8 or 16 loads and then a block of that many stores.  A smart compiler will reuse the same register every time, because there's no reason not to (because of HW register renaming).  See http://agner.org/optimize/